# Joining three tables with sum in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, join, sum

I have three tables:

1. `Sales.SalesOrderHeader`:

   - `SalesOrderID` (PK)
   - `OrderDate`
   - `TotalDue,SalesPersonID`
   - ...
2. `Sales.SalesPerson`:

   - `BusinessEntityID` (PK)
   - ...
3. `Person.Person`:

   - `BusinessEntityID` (PK)
   - `FirstName`
   - `LastName`
   - ...

The table `SalesPerson` acts like an associate entity, which only contributes a common PK (same name as in `Person` and named as `SalesPersonID` in `SalesOrderHeader`).

Now I want to display a table like the following:

```
   BusinessEntityID  FirstName  LastName  Total attributed sales
   ----------------  ---------  --------  ----------------------
1  285               Saeeed     Abbas     32323.88
2  287               Amy        Albert    1214323.98
…  …                 …          …         …
```

There are some `salesOrders` with `null` sales Person, so I want to ignore that, and sum up the sales (sum up the `TotalDue`) for the year 2008 by each sales person.

This is my T-SQL code so far:

```
select
    SUM(s.TotalDue) as 'Total attributed sales',
    p.BusinessEntityID,
    p.FirstName,
    p.LastName
from Sales.SalesOrderHeader as s
right outer join Sales.SalesPerson as sp on s.SalesPersonID=sp.BusinessEntityID 
left outer join Person.Person as p on sp.BusinessEntityID=p.BusinessEntityID
where 
s.OrderDate between '2008-01-01 00:00:00.000' and '2008-12-31 23:59:59.999'
and SalesPersonID is not null
group
--Order 
by SalesOrderID, 
SalesPersonID
```

There are no syntax errors, but my query does not work as intended.

The SQL Server's error message is like

> Column 'Person.Person.BusinessEntityID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

So could anyone help me on this please? Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group by all non-aggregate columns in your select.

ie:

```
group by p.BusinessEntityID, p.FirstName, p.LastName
```

Comment: Thanks!that worked. But I found out that the sums of orders for individual salesperson does not sum up to a total amount. Instead when I used an order by Lastname, I found out that the are duplicate salesperson names. Could you help me further on this please

Comment: You should not need to join onto SalesPerson as you said it is simply an associative table. The order which you are performing `group by` is important also. In this case you should not need to group by SalesOrderID or SalesPersonID as you are only selecting BusinessEntityID.

Comment: `select  p.FirstName+p.LastName+'('+p.BusinessEntityID+')' as 'Sales Person',round(SUM(s.TotalDue),2) as 'Total attributed sales'
  from Sales.SalesOrderHeader as s right outer join 
  Sales.SalesPerson as sp 
  on s.SalesPersonID=sp.BusinessEntityID 
  left outer join 
  Person.Person as p
  on sp.BusinessEntityID=p.BusinessEntityID
  where 
  s.OrderDate between '2008-01-01 00:00:00.000' and '2008-12-31 23:59:59.999'
  having SUM(s.TotalDue)>1000000
  Group by  'Sales Person','Total attributed sales'
  order by SUM(s.TotalDue) `

Comment: Hi, now I want to concatenate the frstname and last name as well as the BusinessEntityID, and select only the attributed sale over a million, order by the total attributed sales. the above is what my codes look like, but SQL server says the syntax near the last 'Group' is not correct. Could u help me on this one please? Thanks so much!

Comment: `group by` should be before `having` clauses. In the future consider opening a new question for a new query, and please mark answers as accepted when they have helped you sufficently!

Comment: thanks. But when I tried putting the group by before the where clause, SQL server just says"Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference."I think this maybe because I used the column alias in the group by function?  How can I achieve this? Sorry to bother you so many times. Your help is much appreciatd.

Comment: You should not use aliases in `group by` statements. And `group by` should follow your `where` clause and preceed `having` clauses.